# Is it customary to call it "R-module ring homomorphism"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

Let $R$ be a ring.

Let $M,N$ be rings together with $R$-module structures, but $M,N$ are not $R$-algebras

Let $\phi:M\rightarrow N$ be a ring homomorphism which is also an $R$-module homomorphism.

Is there a name for this or is it okay to call it "an $R$-module ring homomorphism"?

I googled this term but I couldn't find anyone using it.

Here's an example of this homomorphism.

Let $f_1,...,f_n$ be in the center of $R[Y_1,...,Y_m]$.

Then, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\Phi:R[X_1,...,X_n]\rightarrow R[Y_1,...,Y_m]$ such that $\Phi(X_i)=f_i$ and $\Phi(r•1)=r•1$.

Comment: In what sense is $R[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ ***not*** an $R$-algebra...?

Comment: @ZevChonoles let $r,s,t\in R$ if it were an $R$-algebra, then $(r•(tX))(s•X)=(rs)(tX^2)=(rst)X$, but $(r•(tX))(s•X)=(rtX)(sX)=(rts)X^2$. This leads $rst=rts$. This then implies $R$ is commutative

Comment: Say it's a "morphism of $R$-modules and of rings."

Comment: @Rubertos: Apparently the definition is more subtle than I thought ([MathOverflow link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21899/definition-of-an-algebra-over-a-noncommutative-ring)). Personally I'd prefer saying that any ring $S$ equipped with a ring homomorphism $R\to S$ is an $R$-algebra, but I understand your question now.